# How to run Jrebel as standalone?

Tags: jrebel

How to confiugre JRebel as standalone service on Apache Tomcat 7? As a part of configuration I have already included jrebel.jar in JAVA_OPTS environment variable. Still, JRebel is not working.

Comment: you are stuck at what? error messages? don't know what to do next?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One has to include Environment variable for JRebel in startup script.
 As server starts it starts to monitor some location; this decisions are taken using rebel.xml file which must specify fully qualified path. So as any change in files which are being monitored by JRebel which is deployed on your server, it will reload the same class and thus one can see the changes on the fly without restarting whole server.

Comment: Can we paste following code anywhere in the catalinta.bat file??

set JAVA_OPTS=-javaagent:/path/to/jrebel.jar

Answer (score 3):

You need to add jrebel.jar as a "-javaagent" in your startup script.

See this section for tomcat:

http://manuals.zeroturnaround.com/jrebel/standalone/launch-from-command-line.html#tomcat-4-x-5-x-6-x-7-x

When JRebel starts with your tomcat, you will see a big JRebel banner in server standard output.

Comment: Can we paste following code anywhere in the catalinta.bat file ?? I think that would work

set JAVA_OPTS=-javaagent:/path/to/jrebel.jar

Answer (score 0):

You tell jrebel to monitor some files (one can specify this in Rebel.xml). Jrebel jots down the build time of this files. As and when you change your java file and make class files of them it will identify changed files and then it reloads this files on JVM.

Comment: Can we paste following code anywhere in the catalinta.bat file??

set JAVA_OPTS=-javaagent:/path/to/jrebel.jar